# Heroku cannot deploy Java 11 Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, fatal-error

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot app on Heroku ,using Java version 11.0.1. 
The error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project my-project: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
```

After a lot of research, I've found https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java . I've created the `system.properties` file with multiple variations like :

- `java.runtime.version=11`
- `java.runtime.version=11.0.1`

But still, the same error appears while deploying. Spring Boot and Project java version is set to 11.
[image]

And the java version on Windows is set as well on 11.0.1
[image]

And while deploying
[image]

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.manolispapadimitriou</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>my-project</name>
    <description>My Project</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

Comment: have you tried checking your target bytecode version in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler?

Comment: @4dc0 It's 11 as well

Comment: can you please add your pom.xml to the question body?

Comment: added it right now

Comment: what version of Java does your %JAVA_HOME% point to?

Comment: All the variables are pointing out on 11.0.1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184658/discussion-between-4dc0-and-valkon).

Comment: Is your `system.properties` file added to Git? You can check with `git ls-files`.

Comment: @codefinger Yes it's been added.

Comment: What does the command `heroku buildpacks` show?

Comment: Does your app use the Maven Wrapper? It might need to in order to work with Java 11 https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper

Comment: `heroku buildpacks` prints `has no Builldpack URL set`.

Comment: I tried maven wrapper, still heroku rejects the deploy.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I have successfully deployed my application on heroku by adding `system.properties` file in the project root folder.

`system.properties`

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

[image]

`pom.xml`

`<version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>`

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
</dependency>
```

Reference
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version

The solution is working.

Comment: @Muhammad_Shah You saved my CLAN! that is life saving for me Man! You are from Heavens!

Comment: **ATTENTION PLEASE**!! Just a reminder to put your file under `system` not `application` dot `properties`!!

Comment: Works like a charm also for Java 17. Thanks!