# Why when i try push my Spring boot app to heroku it return "Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, heroku

I'm trying to push my Spring boot app to Heroku, but i'm get this error below.

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
   [INFO] Compiling 41 source files to /tmp/build_4ad2779b666eb1cd25b32f96d104b00b/target/classes
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time:  11.273 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-23T14:23:48Z
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project algamoney-api: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

!     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed

I checked the JAVA_HOME, `java -version`, `java -version` and `mvn -version` all points to the same java version: 11.0.3

My POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.5.RELEASE
         
    
    com.hugo.algamoney-api
    algamoney-api
    1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    algamoney-api
    Workshop Spring Boot com mongodb

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencia do hibernate e Jackson para funcionar o datatype -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Pega a causa da exceção -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Hi @Hugo! You may check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604111/heroku-cannot-deploy-java-11-spring-boot-app Looks very similar to your issue. Hope it helps!

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set incorrect....

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise! JAVA_HOME is set correctly, the problem was not that

Comment: I doubt cause the failure `invalid target release: 11` looks like your JAVA_HOME is pointing to a wrong JDK version  less than 9...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

problem solved! After a lot of try and error it works, i will post below the steps that i take:

1. Change the entire project to java 11, for some reassy the JRE of the project whas in the 1.8 version;
2. Create a `system.properties` whitch the follow Configuration: `java.runtime.version=11.0.3`;
3. Commit and add push again to heroku;

Comment: Unless you _really_ specifically require `11.0.3`, I suggest that you use `java.runtime.version=11`. This ensures you get the latest Java 11 version on each deploy.

Comment: ` !     ERROR: Unsupported Java version: 11.0.3
       Please check your system.properties file to ensure the java.runtime.version
       is among the list of supported version on the Dev Center:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions
       You can also remove the system.properties from your repo to install
       the default 1.8 version.
       If you continue to have trouble, you can open a support ticket here:
       https://help.heroku.com
       Thanks,
       Heroku`

Comment: java.runtime.version specification in system.properties file also works for deployin java 17 apps in Heroku

Answer (score 1):

In pom.xml

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

also once do

```
$ mvn clean install
```

Comment: Can't find maven-compiler-plugin after changing java.version to 1.8

Comment: But changing java.version to 1.8 solved deployment issue on Heroku so thanks!