# Maven is not using Java 11: error message "Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to compile my project with Java 11.

When I try to run the application with Java 8 as the Java version in *pom.xml*, it works fine. But when I try to run it with Java 11, it throws an error.

> Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11

I've tried to fix it in various ways, like changing the environment variable, updating the path, and pointing %JAVA_HOME% to Java 11.

The commands and their results as on my computer are as follows:

```
java -version
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Output:

```
java version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8
```

I am using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) and have made the necessary changes as suggested in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion).

My *pom.xml* file looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>1</version>
                    <projectId>businessapplication-6963d</projectId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I check the Maven version, it shows JDK 1.8 as the Java version:

```
mvn --version
```

Output:

```
Java version: 1.8.0_241, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre
```

How can I point Maven to Java 11? Or, if that is not the problem, how to solve this issue? I don't think that this question is a duplicate of [invalid target release: 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291691/fatal-error-compiling-invalid-target-release-1-8-help-1), as I have already implemented the solutions provided in that thread.

Error after building the project:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The path environment variable is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Delhi 2.0\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\Flutter\flutter\flutter\bin;
C:\Users\Infinity97\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;
C:\Users\Infinity97\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2\bin;
H:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin;
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib;
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox
```

Comment: Where do you get the error in IntelliJ or in the console?

Comment: Once I ran mvn clean install -DskipTests on the terminal.

Comment: And in terminal JAVA_HOME is pointing to JDK 11?

Comment: Yes as written on the question.

Comment: And what Maven version are you using? Did you install this and has it any settings.xml configuration?

Comment: Do you have any other Java build in your Path environment variable?

Comment: What is javac -version? Add %JAVA_HOME%\bin as the first value in path env variable. Seems you have multiple java version on the system. IN your path variable do u have oracle DB installed?  Share your path variable output.

Comment: Updated the question to have the full Error I can see. 
maven version is 3.6.3
I have a project where I use JAVA 8. But presently I have only Java 11 in my Path Env Variable.

Comment: Please print the output of the Path env. variable. And print javac -version output too.. Can you run the on command prompt just use mvn -e clean install

Comment: javac -version is javac 11.0.8

Comment: Updated Path Environment Variable information to the Question.

Comment: Amit Vyas. What do you mean by adding %JAVA_HOME%\bin in my path Variable as the first entry to the path variable. Does heirarchy matter as I already have it in the Path Variable.

Comment: @procrastinator How do I set JAVA_HOME in mvn.bat?

Comment: In your case you have correct. What is your M2_HOME? And Why you have 2 maven entries in D and H drive?

Comment: You always do like create JAVA_HOME and set java without bin before the home path and refer the %JAVA_HOME%\bin as an entry in the path. No hard coding of the java path in the PATH variable. Then have M2_HOME and add a maven path without a bin folder value. In PATH variable set %M2_HOME%\bin as value. Then open new command prompt and run java -version , javac -version mvn -verion and mvn -e clean install. As @procrastinator make sure you don't have a hardcoded path in mvn.bat file. Delete all hardcoding from the PATH variable for java and maven home before doing above steps.

Comment: @procrastinator Updating JAVA_HOME in mvn.cmd(mvn.bat is mvn.cmd in maven 3.5 and above) worked. 
Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it as the answer. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @AmitVyas Thanks for the guidance. Will update my Path variables as the norm. Thanks so much for the effort.

Comment: @AyushSurana for troubleshooting it is oki to set JAVA Home explicit in the maven bat/shell file but you should not. Clean up your path/java home/maven home and everything should work seamlessly. Avoid setting explicit values in the maven as if u will try jdk 8 or 13 or 14 it will fail. Changing JAVA_HOME for nay value will make all dependent apps to work seamlessly.

Comment: A similar (and solved!) question for Heroku's Maven JDK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60817038/why-when-i-try-push-my-spring-boot-app-to-heroku-it-return-fatal-error-compilin

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It seems like you're having the `JAVA_HOME` set in your `mvn.bat`. It could be pointing to the older version of Java (i.e., 8 in your case).

`set JAVA_HOME=C:\path\to\jdk11`. Try using it on the first line, before calling Maven.

Comment: what if my `mvn.bat` is using `set "JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"`

Comment: @G.Ciardini in that case, try checking the variable defined as `%JAVA_HOME%` and updating it.

Comment: my `%JAVA_HOME%` and `java -version` are using jdk12.. so I have to use exactly jdk11?

Comment: If you want to use `jdk11` in your project then yes. Or else `jdk12`.

Comment: @G.Ciardini, If you have JDK12 installed, it will compile JDK11 code.  When you asked **Do I have to use exactly jdk11?**, the answer is no.  As long as you compile with JDK11 **or higher** you can compile code written using the Java 11 syntax.

Answer (score 18):

I was experiencing this issue while trying to deploy a [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) application to [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku).

My JAVA_HOME was set correctly, but I was still receiving same error.

But then this worked for me:

In your *pom.xml* file, add or adapt to your own context:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is just rolling back to Java 8, not making Java 11 work.

Comment: I came across this question while trying to run a Java 8 project (while I have Java 11 installed as well). This solution works perfectly

Comment: I added this plugin to my pox.xml but IDE can't find it, what should be done?

Answer (score 8):

If other people are having this same problem, but with [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) (I know OP was referring to IntelliJ IDEA), also check the JRE in use for Maven:

- Run configurations...
- Select your Maven Build configuration
- Click the JRE tab and choose the JRE version in accordance with your [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. Setting JAVA_HOME environment variable to the right JDK solved my problem.

java -version was showing the right version, but **echo %JAVA_HOME%** pointed to the wrong JDK. Fixing it, solved this issue for me.

Comment: this is a duplicate of the answer that is already accepted on this question.

Comment: Hi Jad, I added this comment because it was written to to check for JAVA_HOME, and I was checking JAVA_VERSION. SO, I mentioned about both in one comment. Please check all the answers above.

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget to change JRE version appropriately in the Run As --> Run Configurations --> JRE tab in Eclipse IDE..

[image: Run Configurations - JRE Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even the correct Java version 11 and JAVA_HOME variable was set.

Switching to another Java vendor from AdoptOpenJDK to Corretto solved it.

You can use [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/install) to change easily and quick between different Java versions and vendors. (the JAVA_HOME variable will set automatically correct by SDKMAN).

Install SDKMAN by:

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Then enter in the terminal:

```
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

To ensure installation was successful:

```
sdk version
```

Install Java 11:

```
sdk install java 11.0.13.8.1-amzn
sdk default java 11.0.13.8.1-amzn
```

To check the versions, runtime and vendor:

```
java --version
mvn -v
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and the easiest way is to use SDKMAN https://sdkman.io/:

1. Install JDK 11 with:

   ```
   sdk install 11.0.11.hs-adpt
   ```

   - `sdk list java` for the list of available JDK
2. Create a .sdkmanrc file in your project main directory:

   ```
   java=11.0.11.hs-adpt
   ```
3. Switch JDK

   - use `sdk env` for switch to right JDK.
   - For automatic switch to the chosen jdk version, enable it in sdkman config file (`~/.sdkman/etc/config`)

     ```
     sdkman_auto_env=true
     ```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error when packaging using Maven from VSCode.  I just needed to add the `release` element to the mavin maven-compiler-plugin in the pom.xml like this:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thank you to Bing Chat to nail that one!

Comment: adding this results in a different failure, for me: Fatal error compiling... : invalid flag: --release

Answer (score -2):

First run

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

This will list all the possible **JAVA_HOME** paths possible on your machine.

You have two options:

Add the line (project permanent)

```
JAVA_HOME="/path/to/obtained/from/command/lib"
```

in your *maven.bat* file, ideally right after the initial comments.

Run

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/obtained/from/command/lib
```

Before running the mvnw command.

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably? What edition / version was this tested on? [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10)?

Answer (score -3):

1. Check the Java home under path inside environment variables. It should point to JDK 11 under your Java installation directory,
2. Check for the below inside file *pom.xml*

   ```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
   ```
3. Under *Path*, check the correct entry for %JAVA_HOME% environment variable and explicitly set JAVA_HOME=C:\tools\java\jdk11
4. Check, your mvn should not be overriding the Java version 11

Comment: This is just rolling back to Java 8, not making Java 11 work

Comment: This is not the answer to this question

Comment: This sounds like referring to [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows). Is it?

Answer (score -6):

This what helped me:

```
<properties>
     <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>
```

The issue must be you are using 8 locally, but pointing to a different version in your *pom.xml*.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68105347/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -7):

Just change this

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

to

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: He's trying to make it work successfully using Java 11, not roll back to Java 8

Comment: This is just rolling back to Java 8, not making Java 11 work.

Comment: I guess @Farhad missed the joke commented by Scott Baker. :-D