# Maven Java error compiling on build: maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven

When I try to run as maven build it always give `BUILD FAILURE`.

```java
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project testJPA: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
```

I already tried the following things:

- remove .m2 folder
- reinstall eclipse
- set executable on pom.xml
- set build option to clean

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"

> echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
```

---

pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

None of them worked. Any guesses?

Comment: It might have to do with Java 11. Do you have java 11 installed ? take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63154787/maven-is-not-using-java-11-fatal-error-compiling-invalid-target-release-11

Comment: I updated my question with the results

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of suggestions regarding setting version in pom. Can you add your pom.xml content to question ?

Comment: Also what does "mvn –version" produce on command line ?

Comment: As I don't have `Apache Maven` it doesn't have that command.

Comment: @AntiqTech I added just the important part of the xml I think, SO doesn't allow much code.

Comment: <source>11</source>
<target>11</target>
These are the parts I see gets updated in the examples.   Try replacing 11 with 1.8 since you have 1.8 version installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.

I installed JDK 11 and set it at **Window** > **Preferences** > **Java** > **Installed JREs** > **Add** > **jdk-11.0.9**

Downloaded at: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html