# Compilation failure cannot access io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager [ERROR] bad class webdrivermanager\5.4.1\

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, webdrivermanager-java

Hi All anyone could help me? I faced an issue when Itried running using Maven command line `mvn test'`,
based on issue report , the issue due to webdriver dependency 5.4.1 version.

Java that I used "11 version"

Below are dependencies I use :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
```

[screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QLow.png)

i tried running my selenium using maven command line,

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the source/target versions for your maven-compiler-plugin, it should be 11, not 1.8:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Provided dependencies/plugins are poorly formatted in the original question, I believe that the mentioned plugin is located inside of the /build/plugins

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , however after changed the target version to 11. i facing this issue, could you help me ?

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.2:compile (default-compile) on project logislyAT: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]

Comment: @user23261610, can you check the Java version that is installed in your system? (java -version from CMD).  And also check the SDK version in your IDE

Comment: this my java version = java version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19 LTS
and this the sdk on my IDE =  oracle openJDK version 11.0.16

Comment: @user23261610, can you also check the maven java version? See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63155672/23182657

Comment: Hi sashkins, issue has been fixed and thanks for helping my issue