# Failed to upload spring boot to heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku

In application.properties I specified java and maven version as

```
java.runtime.version=11
maven.version=4.0.0
```

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project heroku-spring: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11

How can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe this is related to your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604111/heroku-cannot-deploy-java-11-spring-boot-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change maven and java versions in your pom.xml file.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating `system.properties` file with the property `java.runtime.version=11`  in the root directory helped me with the same problem.