# Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 during pushing to heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

im trying to deploy my back end application to heroku
bun when I run this command

```
git push --force heroku-be-app splitting-staging-be:master
```

im getting this error

```
       [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M9/qdox-2.0-M9.jar (317 kB at 7.6 MB/s)
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [INFO] Compiling 24 source files to /tmp/build_4e875976/target/classes
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  12.593 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-21T15:28:14Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project backend: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

This is my pom file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>vs</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>Main server voor van streek project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>   <!-- maven.compiler.source  -->
                    <target>15</target> <!-- maven.compiler.target -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Doesn't [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53604111/2915423) help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by adding a new file **system.properties** and the content added to the file is **java.runtime.version=11** (For me I am using JDK 11).

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

Comment: It's important that the file is next to your pom.xml, I had troubles because I automatically put it in src/main/resources where it appears to not be found.

Answer (score 3):

I would try focusing on why maven complains about invalid release 11 (`Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11`).

As seen in your `pom.xml` config you clearly intend to use version 15, so I would suggest to investigate why there is a problem with version 11.

Check `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable, `system.properties` file, etc.

Also try debug route suggested in [official docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version) or a [Q&A on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53604111/2915423).

Answer (score 1):

You must use the specific version of Java supported by Heroku. The following versions supported are:

- Java 7 - 1.7.0_292
- Java 8 - 1.8.0_282
- Java 11 - 11.0.10
- Java 13 - 13.0.6
- Java 15 - 15.0.2

Set a java.runtime.version property of the system.properties file, create a system.properties file if one does not already exist.

java.runtime.version = SUPPORTED_VERSION

Read more in [heroku-java-support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions)

Comment: This solution fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have experienced today.

I have been using jdk 1.8, and then have to install jdk 1.11.

But, after running `mvnw` through my shell script file `dep.sh`, it failed to build jar.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

MVN=$(pwd)/mvnw
echo "[1/2] Building app.jar ..."
$MVN clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

- `dep.sh` calls mvnw script file with goal `clan package`

##### Error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile
  (default-compile) on project dictation:
  Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My `pom.xml` is configured with jdk 1.11. But it does not solve the build error.

```xml
<project ...>
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <source>11</source><!-- 1.11 not working -->
          <target>11</target><!-- 1.11 not working -->
       </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

- build failure

When I installed jdk 1.8, `JAVA_HOME` was set to `/my/jdk/1.8/dir`, which is used for bundling jar.

I set `JAVA_HOME` to `/my/jdk/1.111/dir` in `dep.sh`, it works without error.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

JAVA_HOME="/C/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.9"

MVN=$(pwd)/mvnw
echo "[1/2] Building app.jar ..."
$MVN clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Answer (score 0):

create system.properties file and Add java.runtime.version=11

[image]