# Deploying Spring Boot application to Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy Spring Boot application to Heroku but I am not able to do that. My application is automatically get detected as "heroku-maven-plugin" but i want to deploy it as Java Application.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look on it https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-heroku-and-cicd

Comment: getting this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/development/searchbooks/SearchBooksApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: I am not able to override the jdk version of heroku which is 1.8

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604111/heroku-cannot-deploy-java-11-spring-boot-app

Comment: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-03T07:06:31.599486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar --server.port=21791 target/search-books-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`
2021-05-03T07:06:34.655559+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-05-03T07:06:34.660959+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/search-books-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

Comment: @KayisRahman Your links helped me alot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer for this issue.

- Added system.properties file at the root folder path

  ```
  java.runtime.version=14
  ```
- deployed app through heroku-cli-deploy

  ```
  Step 1: mvn clean
  Step 2: mvn build
  Step 3: heroku deploy:jar target/*.jar --app <app-name>
  ```